# Is this question in the correct forum?

Tags: support

I have doubts about [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455755), because it is a question about a software of physics but I don't know if the question is in the correct forum.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's not on topic. According to our meta site ([1](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/should-we-allow-software-questions), [2](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-2), [3](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-3)), questions about how to use software *may* be on topic when the software in question is something designed for and primarily used in physics, but questions asking for software recommendations are generally off topic (unless the purpose of the software is educational, similar to how a textbook would be used). I think your question falls into the latter category.